# php $_GET with no variable

Tags: php, get

I want to have the URL http://something.com/somestring where the somestring is picked up by the php `$_GET`, instead of having to write http://something.com/index.php?var=somestring and inside php using `$_GET["var"]`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has already been answered. But to give you the common example for your case:

```
RewriteEngine
RewriteCond ./%{REQUEST_URI}  !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$   index.php?var=$1   [L]
```

The first cond prevents the rule from rewriting requests to real files. The second takes any alphanumeric string and appends it as GET parameter to your script.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on Apache, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/). Other servers have different methods, but the general term us 'URL rewriting' to describe this functionality.

Comment: For IIS there is ISAPI_REWRITE what is nearly the same as mod_rewrite but it isn't free

Comment: so does that then change the URL so php can understand what to $_GET?

Comment: Well, yes, but there is some configuration required. It kind of does an 'internal' redirect, so your page is called as index.php?face=palm, but the user accesses it via /palm. It can be as simple or as complex as you like, and work based on simple criteria or regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to do this, assuming you are using apache as webserver -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into .htaccess and [mod_rewrite](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`

http://something.com/index.php?=somestring

`$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` would return "somestring"